# How to limit a Bundle by a Role

Tags: bundles

It is possible to use Role based restriction on a Page and with multimedia Component, but we don't have that option when dealing with Bundles.

Any suggestions how to restrict Bundles based on Roles?

Comment: IIRC, bundles are Virtual Folders.

Comment: I believe Bundles are indeed Virtual Folders under-the-hood (at least that's what you explained to us way back when :-) ). And early Bundle workflow code needed an extra check to know something was a Bundle rather than a virtual folder. But something can tell the difference, though, as we have both Virtual Folder and Bundle management rights in Publication properties.

Answer (score 4):

The Tridion authorization model is based on users and groups with control over:

- Group Membership **Scope** for Publication visibility
- **Rights** for the ability to use certain commands (e.g. create Components)
- **Privileges** for system-wide abilities
- **Permissions** (read, write, delete, localize) for control over items for a given Organizational Item (Folder, Structure Group, or Category)

You can control access to Bundles by:

- Limiting Permissions of the folders that contain them
- Adding/removing Rights for Bundles in Publications for select groups

*I believe you might be able to adjust the permissions of the Bundle itself (prevent adding items) as well as hide Bundle schemas through permissions on their folders, but I haven't set up an authorization model in a while.*

Privileges are also extendable if you need additional functionality, but you probably have enough "dials" for your use cases.

See my [introduction post to Authorization](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/07/sdl-tridion-authorization.html) blog post for reference.

Comment: For completeness: a bundle is just a list of items that are grouped together for some arbitrary purpose. An item can be in more than one bundle, and it might make sense to create separate bundles for use by different groups. By placing them in different folders, you could control which groups can use them.